# gym env.render() on Nth step

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am using `gym==0.26.0` and I am trying to make my environment render only on each Nth step. So that my nn is learning fast but that I can also see some of the progress as the image and not just rewards in my terminal. With the newer versions of gym, it seems like I need to specify the `render_mode` when creating but then it uses just this render mode for all renders.

How to make the `env.render()` render it as "human" only for each Nth episode? (it seems like you order the one and only render_mode in env.make)

Comment: And what is your question? Seems you forgot to include one.

Answer (score 1):

Today I found a new method.
Try `render_mode='rbg_array'`,
Use these when you want to show process.

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(env.render(), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
cv2.imshow("test", img)
cv2.waitKey(50)
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to create a new 'human' env to be used on Nth step.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).